# My cat looks for invisible bugs and i cant see them

Tags: cats

WHAT IS MAH CAT DOIN

also, I'm not that smart so plz don't take me seriously tho my cat IS looking for invisible bugs.

Comment: Hi welcome to Pets, if you want to get serious help in answers then I'm sorry but the question needs to be serious as well, please include all the relevant details or else it will be impossible for anyone to give you any specific advice beyond some generic and trivial ones, it will get you more serious attention if the question is formulated without using slang but I can actually fix that for you once you include the details, until you include them this question needs to be closed because of lack of focus.